# Sulle forme Eneide ed Eneida

Tags: word-usage, history, proper-nouns

Stavo leggendo il canto XXI del *Purgatorio* con l'aiuto delle note di due libri diversi, quelle di Anna Maria Chiavacci Leonardi (Mondadori) e quelle di Emilio Pasquini e Antonio Quaglio (Garzanti).

Quando sono arrivata a queste straordinarie parole di Stazio, mi sono accorta della differenza tra il nome che dà Dante al poema epico di Virgilio e quello che appare nelle note che ho menzionato:

> Al mio ardor fuor seme le faville,
>   
>                 
>   che mi scaldar, de la divina fiamma
>   
>                
>   onde sono allumati più di mille; 96
>   
>   
>                
>   de l'Eneïda dico, la qual mamma
>   
>                
>   fummi, e fummi nutrice, poetando:
>   
>                
>   sanz' essa non fermai peso di dramma. 99

So che nell'italiano di oggi è *Eneide*, ma precisamente questo ha generato il mio primo dubbio: *Eneide* è plurale o singolare?

In passato, quando avevo sentito o letto *Eneide*, avevo sempre pensato che fosse plurale proprio perché è *Eneide* e non *Eneida*. Ma ora me ne rendo conto che nelle note dei libri c'è scritto l'*Eneide* e non le *Eneide*. Quindi, devo dedurre che si tratta di un singolare, vero?

Tuttavia, vedo che per Dante è l'*Eneida*, che in questo canto appare con la dieresi, immagino che come risorsa per ottenere l'endecasillabo. Allora mi chiedo: in passato era l'*Eneida* e, a un certo momento, per qualche ragione, si è passato a dire l'*Eneide*?

Sul [Dizionario d'ortografia e di pronuncia](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=59581&r=10626), però, ho trovato

[image: Eneide sul DOP]

Significa questo che la forma *Eneida* è stata usata solo da Dante?

Comment: Eneide è singolare. La precisazione “in Dante” significa che si trova in Dante, ma potrebbe anche essere stata usata altrove. La dieresi (probabile aggiunta editoriale) serve solo per spezzare il dittongo e non va usata nella normale prosa.

Comment: Considerando che spesso le parole italiane derivanti dal greco o dal latino assumono la loro forma dal tema dell'accusativo (anziché dal nominativo), la butto là, ma potrei dire una fesseria: la forma in “-a” ricalca la (vera nel caso dell'_Iliade_ o possibile, nel caso dell'_Eneide_ che era latina) forma dell'accusativo greco; quella in “-e” è ricalca l'accusativo latino (con caduta della “m” finale).

Comment: @Charo, scusami in anticipo: non è possibile la forma progressiva con il passato prossimo («Ho stato leggendo», quindi dovrebbe essere «Stavo leggendo»).

Comment: Grazie, @Benedetta: ho fatto la correzione.

Comment: @Charo: Prego :-)

Answer (score 2):

La dizione “Eneida” non è stata usata solo da Dante. Guardando su Google Books trovo [“Il libro primo e secondo dell’Eneida di Virgilio”](https://books.google.it/books?id=5fkTAAAAQAAJ) pubblicato nel 1821.

Ma trovo anche [“L’Eneide di Virgilio del commendatore Annibal Caro”](https://books.google.it/books?id=E_vEAAAAMAAJ), pubblicata nel 1760.

Al giorno d’oggi è solo “Eneide” (singolare, ovviamente). Un ngram su Google dà una nettissima prevalenza di “Eneide”.

Si trova anche l'alternativa “Iliada” per “Iliade”.