# Usi di "stare" + gerundio

Tags: word-usage, verbs, tenses

In [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/12809/) avevo scritto

> Ho stato leggendo il canto XXI del *Purgatorio*

ma poi ho cambiato la frase in

> Stavo leggendo il canto XXI del *Purgatorio*

poiché mi si è detto in un commento che la forma "stare" + gerundio non si usa con il passato prossimo. E credo di ricordare che anche qualche altra volta mi si era spiegato in un commento  (che, purtroppo, adesso non riesco a trovare più) che "stare" + gerundio si usa in italiano molto di meno che la costruzione equivalente  in altre lingue.

Posto questa domanda perché gli usi di questa locuzione in italiano non mi sono del tutto chiari.

L'unica informazione al riguardo che sono riuscita a trovare alla sezione  XI.48.c) dell'*Italiano* di Serianni è:

> Svolgimento di un'azione (aspetto progressivo): *stare*+gerundio («che stai facendo?»), *stare a*+infinito («sto a farmi la
> barba» Pirandello, cfr. VII.75a), *andare*+gerundio («via via la casa s'era destata: i rumori si erano andati infoltendo»
> Jovine, *Signora Ava*), *venire*+gerundio
> («Viene il vento recando il suon dell'ora/
> dalla torre del borgo» Leopardi, *Le ricordanze*, 50-51), ecc.

Ma questa spiegazione non chiarisce i miei dubbi su quando e quando non si usa "stare" + gerundio in italiano.

Su questo sito, ho trovato queste due risposte ([[1](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/7245/)] e [[2](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/10938/)]) che fanno riferimento al cosiddetto "imperfetto progressivo". Quindi, diciamo che questo uso mi è chiaro.

So anche che, come nell'esempio di Serianni, posso usare "stare" + gerundio al presente indicativo in frasi come, per esempio,

> In questo momento sto leggendo il canto XXIV del *Purgatorio*.

Mi pare anche che si possa usare "stare" + gerundio con "stare" all'infinito in frasi come, ad esempio,

> Credo di star dimenticando tutto quello che ho imparato durante questi ultimi anni.

Grazie a un commento alla domanda, un altro uso che mi è venuto in mente è quello di "stare" al futuro semplice + gerundio per esprimere un'ipotesi nel momento presente, come in questo esempio:

> Maria non ha un buon aspetto. Le starà venendo la febbre?

Non sono invece sicura che si possa usare la locuzione "stare" al futuro semplice + gerundio per indicare fatti futuri, in frasi come, ad esempio,

> Domani mattina starò viaggiando su un treno.

E, a pensarci meglio, ci sono certe subordinate e altre costruzioni che richiedono il congiuntivo. Quindi, potrei anche fare frasi come

> Credo che in questo momento Maria stia studiando

e anche

> Credeva che Maria stesse studiando, invece stava giocando sul computer.

Quindi, la mia domanda sarebbe soprattutto su altri usi di "stare" + gerundio, se ci sono.

Comment: The very first link on the very first Google query: https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Big_Book_of_Italian_Verbs_900_Fully.html?id=DYynDwAAQBAJ You may want to navigate to the p. 89

Comment: Del resto credo sia logico. "Ho stato facendo" è un rimescolio di aspetti piuttosto strano... Quindi è destinato ad aver un senso indiretto se utilizzato: "potrebbe essere cosî, se non per essere cosî in effetti". Evidentamente l'immagginazione italiana non ha voluto esser cosî contraria alla buona andata dei sensi interni..

Comment: Oh, thanks, @Evgeniy: I'm not really used to this English-based approach to Italian, which, personally, I've never found so useful. And I can assure you that, in my own languages, things like "he estat llegint el cant...", "vaig estar llegint el cant...", "he estado leyendo el canto...", etc. sound perfectly logic.

Comment: Non credo si possa usare "starà venendo" per indicare un'azione futura, come sembra suggerire quel libro, ma forse sì per indicare un'ipotesi nel momento presente.

Comment: Per esempio: "Maria non ha buon aspetto. Le starà venendo la febbre?". Credo che questo si possa dire, ma non ha niente a che vedere con esprimere fatti futuri.

Comment: Ti consiglio di ricercare su Internet "starà superando".

Comment: Le mot clef a été "stetti andando". Ti credo, ma faccio notare che nei "he estat llegint" qualcosa ecc. ci sono due azioni e due aspetti, l'uno ausiliario, cioè "nuovo" e "specialmente inventato"; per questo il rimescolio è evitato. Un'altra visione di tempo; infatti ho sempre detto che gli spagnioli sono più attentivi ai sentimenti sui fatti già fatti (si vede molto nelle pitture), ma non te l'ho detto. If I was learning Ukrainian, I would tend to avoid English, too.. Okay, I stop here.

Comment: @Evgeniy: Se con "starà superando" ti riferisci a [questo esempio](https://books.google.es/books?id=atK2LDno9sEC&pg=PA214&dq=%22star%C3%A0+superando%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqzsOpw6LqAhUZ4OAKHby9A2MQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22star%C3%A0%20superando%22&f=false) (l'unico che mi è apparso su Google Libri), non sono per niente sicura che si tratti di buon italiano (personalmente mi suona molto male). Forse è una cattiva traduzione dell'inglese.

Comment: La pagina non mi è disponibile. No, cercavo su Google comune. Gli esempi sono molti, forse non particolarmente ammaestrati, ma naturalissimi al mio orecchio che puô poi certo sbagliare, sono sicuro che non sono tradotti.

Comment: Non capisco quali siano i tuoi dubbi. L’uso di stare all’infinito + gerundio e di stare al futuro +gerundio?

Comment: Una ricerca Google su "credo di stare dimenticando" lascia parecchi esempi inclusa una frase da Vilo Mei che sembra essere un autore pop italiano (ho trovato la sua pagina su Facebook). Noto anche che qui parliamo dell'infinito solo tecnicamente poiché il centro della proposizione è nel "credo" che è nel presente. Puô essere importante o no, pure bisognerebbe notarlo.

Comment: @Hachi: Veramente il dubbio è soltanto su "stare" al futuro semplice + gerundio. Ho cercato di scriverlo nella domanda. Non si capisce? Vedi dove ho scritto "È così?".

Comment: Quindi se è corretta una frase tipo “Dov’è  la mamma? Sarà in camera sua,  starà dormendo!”

Comment: “Maria non ha buon aspetto. ***Le*** (non gli) starà venendo la febbre?“

Comment: @Hachi: Se capisco bene, all'OP è chiaro l'uso di futuro+gerundio per indicare un'ipotesi, un'eventualità, che è quello dell'esempio contenuto nella domanda e del tuo esempio sulla mamma che dorme. Diverso è il caso di una frase come “Domani a quest'ora starò passeggiando per il Bois de Boulogne”. Personalmente, non mi sembra l'italiano più elegante, ma non è una cosa mai sentita.

Comment: @DaG - ok, adesso l’esempio è più  chiaro (forse andrebbe inserito nella domanda per completezza.) Ma come dice questo articolo della Crusca “*La perifrasi stare + gerundio è senza dubbio un costrutto molto ricorrente nell’italiano contemporaneo, in particolare nel parlato spontaneo, e presente,*” Per cui, a parte l’eleganza, non escluderei l’uso con senso del futuro. https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/stai-leggendo-la-risposta-sulla-perifrasi-progressiva-stare--gerundio-del-verbo-stare-e-del-verbo-essere/1413

Comment: Sì, grazie, @Hachi: ho sbagliato il pronome.

Comment: @Hachi: Ho modificato leggermente la domanda. Spero che adesso si capisca meglio.

Comment: Scusa c’è un altro errore nella frase  (manca l’articolo) : “‘Maria non ha ***un*** bell’aspetto.” —— Con riferimento a persona, figura, sembianza, specialmente  del volto “Avere un aspetto florido, lieto, triste, corrucciato; “ http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/aspetto1/

Comment: “Credo di star dimenticando” non è una costruzione che userei, anche se non è “scorretta”. La “forma progressiva” si usa molto meno in italiano che in inglese.

Comment: È precisamente per questa ragione che ho posto la domanda, @egreg.

Comment: @egreg: Tuttavia, potrei dire "credo che Maria stia dimenticando tutto quello che ha imparato a scuola?"

Comment: @Charo Certo; è l'infinito che mi disturba l'orecchio.